# Replace material to material

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to add sprite to player material with script. I have a shop menu of player and when a like to select one sprite i like to add to player material but I don't know how to do this. I have my code but just this I don't know how to add. This is my code I made like this but don't work can someone tell me how to add playerSprite to playermaterial.

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ShopMenuNew : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform spritePanel;

    public Text spriteBuySetText;
    public Text goldText;

    [SerializeField]
    private int[] spriteCost;
    private int selectedSpriteIndex;
    private int activeSpriteIndex;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

        GameManager.Instance.state.gold = 999;

        UpdateGoldText();

        InitShop();

        OnSpriteSelect(GameManager.Instance.state.activeSprite);
        SetSprite(GameManager.Instance.state.activeSprite);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    private void InitShop()
    {
        if (spritePanel == null)
            Debug.Log("You did not asign the sprite panel in the inspector");

        int i = 0;
        foreach (Transform t in spritePanel)
        {
            int currentIndex = i;

            Button b = t.GetComponent<Button>();
            b.onClick.AddListener(() => OnSpriteSelect(currentIndex));

            Image img = t.GetComponent<Image>();
            img.sprite = GameManager.Instance.IsSpriteOwned(i) ? GameManager.Instance.playerSprite[currentIndex] : GameManager.Instance.playerSpriteBuy[currentIndex] ;

            i++;
        }

    }

    private void SetSprite(int index)
    { 
        activeSpriteIndex = index;
        GameManager.Instance.state.activeSprite = index;
        GameManager.Instance.playerMaterial = GameManager.Instance.playerSprite[index];

        spriteBuySetText.text = "Current";
        GameManager.Instance.Save();
    }


    private void UpdateGoldText()
    {
        goldText.text = GameManager.Instance.state.gold.ToString();
    }

    private void OnSpriteSelect(int currentIndex)
    {
        Debug.Log("Selecting color button :" + currentIndex);

        if (selectedSpriteIndex == currentIndex)
            return;



        selectedSpriteIndex = currentIndex;

        if (GameManager.Instance.IsSpriteOwned(currentIndex))
        {
            if (activeSpriteIndex == currentIndex)
            {
                spriteBuySetText.text = "Current";
            }
            else
            {
                spriteBuySetText.text = "Select";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            spriteBuySetText.text = "Buy: " + spriteCost[currentIndex].ToString();
        }
    }

    public void OnSpriteBuySet()
    {
        Debug.Log("Buy Sprite");

        if (GameManager.Instance.IsSpriteOwned(selectedSpriteIndex))
        {
            SetSprite(selectedSpriteIndex);
            GameManager.Instance.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            if(GameManager.Instance.BuySprite(selectedSpriteIndex,spriteCost[selectedSpriteIndex]))
            {
                SetSprite(selectedSpriteIndex);
                spritePanel.GetChild(selectedSpriteIndex).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = GameManager.Instance.playerSprite[selectedSpriteIndex];

                UpdateGoldText();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Not enough Gold");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static GameManager Instance { set; get; }
    public SaveState state;

    public int currentSkinIndex = 0;
    public int currency = 0;
    public int skinAvilability = 1;
    public int coins;

    public Material playerMaterial;
    public Sprite[] playerSprite;
    public Sprite[] playerSpriteBuy;
    public Texture[] textures;


    private void Awake ()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        Instance = this;
        Load();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("save",Helper.Serialize<SaveState>(state));
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("save"))
        {
            state = Helper.Deserialize<SaveState>(PlayerPrefs.GetString("save"));
        }
        else
        {
            state = new SaveState();
            Save();
            Debug.Log("No Save file found, creating a new one!");
        }
    }

    public bool IsSpriteOwned(int index)
    {
        return (state.spriteOwned & (1 << index)) != 0;
    }

    public void UnlockSprite(int index)
    {
        state.spriteOwned |= 1 << index;
    }

    public bool BuySprite(int index, int cost)
    {
        if(state.gold >= cost)
        {
            state.gold -= cost;
            UnlockSprite(index);

            Save();

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void ResetSave()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("save");
    }


}
```

[image: Screenshot of game]

Answer (score 1):

So your `playerMaterial` property here isn't actually....useful.

It's basically a 3x5 index card with the name of a book written on it, it's not the actual book.  So when you do this:

```
GameManager.Instance.playerMaterial = GameManager.Instance.otherMaterial[index];
```

You're erasing the name of the book on the index card and writing in the title of a new book and then wondering why the bookshelf's contents didn't change.  It didn't change because you never actually did anything TO the bookshelf.

You need to change the material property *of the player's `Renderer` component* in order for it to change.

E.g. something like...

```
GameManager.Instance.player.getComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial = GameManager.Instance.otherMaterial[index];
```

Comment: Can i add sprite to material with this code public Sprite[] otherMaterial;

Comment: @Toni https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-mainTexture.html

Comment: @Toni of course not. Those are two different types. In order to solve your problem (which is different than your question and should be posted as a new question) you have to explain what the hell you're trying to do. Are you trying to assign *one* of those sprites to the player? Are you trying to assign each of those sprites to *a part of the player?* What are you doing?

Comment: to assign one of those sprites to the player? Like a shop Menu Look the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCXxB.png  and to save the sprite in all scene thank You

Comment: You use an [index].

Comment: Yes i use a [index] for which sprite is select and to add sprite to the player.

Comment: @Toni Then please adequately describe your problem.

Comment: Look the new code with the sprite and here wher is my problem: GameManager.Instance.playerMaterial = GameManager.Instance.playerSprite[index]; and its says this error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Sprite' to `UnityEngine.Material'

Comment: Again, your not actually assigning the sprite *to the object.* You're just putting it in a field that has no useful purpose.  Congrats, you stored it on a 3x5 reference card.  But no where have you done anything that actually *assigns it to the object's renderer!*

Comment: @Toni Adding all of your code was a good idea. Thanks. However, my statement still stands: You need to assign the material *to the game object's renderer* or it does nothing.

Comment: how to add can you tell me please i have a player ball with Meshrender

Comment: i have still this error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Sprite' to `UnityEngine.Material'

Comment: @Toni A sprite is a texture, a material encompasses everything needed to render the object: color, specular intensity, reflections, shader.... You need to assign the sprite to material's texture. Same as you would in the inspector.  Your question was dealing with materials, I answered based on materials.